# An identity for the higher form Levi-Civita connection

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Take $M$ a Riemannian manifold and $\Lambda^1$ its space of one forms. The LCC (Levi-Civita connection) $\nabla:\Lambda^1 \to \Lambda^1 \otimes \Lambda^1$ is well known to satisfy the identity $m \circ \nabla = d$ for $m: \Lambda^1 \otimes \Lambda^1 \to \Lambda^1$ the usual exterior algebra multiplication and $d$ the exterior derivative. The LCC can be extended to higher forms in the [standard way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264340/levi-civita-connection-on-forms) $\nabla:\Lambda^k \to \Lambda^k \otimes \Lambda^1$. But does this $\nabla$ still satisfy the obvious higher identity $m \circ \nabla = d$?

Comment: do you mean  $m: \Lambda^1 \otimes \Lambda^1 \to \Lambda^2$?

Answer (score 3):

Both $m∘∇$ and $d$ are natural operations from $k$-forms to $(k+1)$-forms.

By Palais's theorem, all such operations are proportional to the de Rham differential.
That is, $m∘∇=λd$ for some $λ$.

By examining the case of ${\bf R}^n$ with the standard metric, we see that the proportionality constant $λ$ equals 1.

Comment: It is not clear to me why $m\circ\nabla$ is natural, since it appears to depend on $\nabla$ which is not natural.

Comment: what is  Palais theorem precisely?

Comment: @BenMcKay  I  do not  know  what is  Palais  theorem  precisely  but it seems that your  comment  somewhat is  also  applicable  to Palais  theorem  too(according to $m\circ \nabla=\lambda d$ for  a  constant $\lambda$

Comment: Palais's theorem appeared in Palais, R., Natural operations on differential forms, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 92 (1959), 125–141. It says that the only diffeomorphism invariant operators on differential forms are constant multiples of the exterior derivative and the identity operator.